# PC not turning on at all after installing a new GPU

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, gpu

My pc does not turn on at all. I press the button, nothing happens.

I installed a working GT 210.

What I did is:

- PC was turning on normally for more than 4 years, I turned it off.
- I removed the GT 210 to see the igpu performance, normal boot, drivers and stuff.
- I turned it off, put the GT 210 inside again, no boot.
- I removed it, nothing again, power cable is plugged correctly.

  windows 10
  intel core2 duo e8500
  slow hdd

Comment: Sounds like you accidently disconnected a required cable.  Check all requires cables are connected

Comment: they are all in

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.... deleted my answer

Comment: @MartoxD - Did your machine have a GPU before you installed one?

Comment: it came with no gpu 4 years ago, worked fine with the gt 210, and today it just died like that

Comment: @Ramhound ok, after a few mins unpluged, i plueged it back it tured on for 3 sec and went off, no output to a monitor and no hdd inside right now, should i put them back and try again?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware fault.  You will have to diagnose each individual component

Comment: it is on! only thing i did is to unplug it for a few minutes
i got scared for a few minutes that it died, i have no clue what happend, but it is on and running right now, thanks for your time and efford Ramhoud

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your Mobo CMOS by either removing the battery or shorting the reset BIOS pins.

Comment: one of the pins is bend, not the pins for clr cmos, the clr cmosshw i think

Comment: @MartoxD - You should verify that.  It's not clear how one of the pins, to a cable you didn't tough, became bent though.

Comment: I am sorry this answer does not make sense.  The machine will not even turn on, this is a hardware problem, performing a CMOS reset won't solve the reason the machine refuses to turn on.

Comment: this is bend

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/803149498724646952/816369628723806218/IMG_20210302_195935.jpg (send from my phone to my discord so i can copy the link)

Comment: I've had a similar issue when I went from a 3400G Ryzen 5 APU to CPU+5600XTGPU configuration, resetting my mobo solved the issue. Nevertheless, the bent pin on the picture should not interfere with the ability to reset the CMOS, since you can simply remove the battery with the power cord unplugged and wait about 5 minutes.